# Wordpress Tinymce editor on content text selection event

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, customization

In wordpress admin side tinymce editor by default showing disable buttons of Hyperlink. When we select any text from editor then link/unlink buttons become active. I want exact event. How can I enable my custom buttons on content text selection? and also need to disable while deselecting the text.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-functionality-to-the-wordpress-visual-editor/)

This was shared to me no so long ago whilst i had a similar question.
As mentioned by an other user that i should include the code in case the link breaks, this should be the part that might help you

```
    // Enable/disable the button on the node change event
    editor.onNodeChange.add(function( editor ) {
        // Get selected text, and assume we'll disable our button
        var selection = editor.selection.getContent();
        var disable = true;

        // If we have some text selected, don't disable the button
        if ( selection ) {
            disable = false;
        }
        // Define whether our button should be enabled or disabled
        editor.controlManager.setDisabled( 'custom_class', disable );
    });
```